# How to set fan profiles in a Gigabyte G291 server?

Tags: fan, linux-server

I have a server (Gigabyte G291-281), and I'd like to change the fan profile to make the fans work in a constant speed instead of throttling back and forth between low and high speeds.

When I access the BMC, I see there's a single fan profile, and within it 60 different policies with various graphs (for a sensor input -> fan duty cycle).

I'm not sure how to select between them, or how the server chooses what to use. I couldn't find any information in the server manual.

I appreciate any help!